# DockPanel Suite: Dynamically set FloatWindow's MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I'm farily new to DockPanel Suite. I have created a custom FloatWindow and IFloatWindowFactory like this:

```cs
public class MapFloatWindowFactory : DockPanelExtender.IFloatWindowFactory
{
    public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane, Rectangle bounds)
    {
        return new MapFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane, bounds);
    }

    public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane)
    {
        return new MapFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class MapFloatWindow : FloatWindow
{
    public MapFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane) : base(dockPanel, pane)
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }

    public MapFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane, Rectangle bounds) : base(dockPanel, pane, bounds)
    {
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
    }
}
```

However with this approach, the `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` property of my `DockContent` is not respected. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

As per DockPanel Suite documentation (http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/en/latest/tutorials/customizing-floatwindow.html), you really need to create a custom float window factory:

> Next, create a factory class to create the CustomFloatWindow. This is
>   done by implementing the IFloatWindowFactory interface,
>
> ```
> public class CustomFloatWindowFactory :
>         DockPanelExtender.IFloatWindowFactory
> {
>     public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane, Rectangle bounds)
>     {
>         return new CustomFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane, bounds);
>     }
>
>     public FloatWindow CreateFloatWindow(DockPanel dockPanel, DockPane pane)
>     {
>         return new CustomFloatWindow(dockPanel, pane);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Lastly, attach the new factory to the DockPanel control,
>
> ```
> this.dockPanel.Extender.FloatWindowFactory = new CustomFloatWindowFactory();
> ```